# Pythonnet output encoding

Tags: python, .net, unicode, locale, python.net

I want to call Python with C# and My solution is to use Pythonnet lib ( https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet ).

But I got a problem when testing it with their sample code. My output string becomes garbled. Here is my code and my output string. Does anyone know what the problem is?  Thank you in advance.

[image]

Here is my output result.

[image]

And my environment is Windows 10 Traditional Chinese version, Visual Studio Community 2017, Python 36.

Comment: this is probably your issue (some interesting locale): https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/220

Comment: @denfromufa , Thank  you. my environment is win 10 Chinese version. So it is possible. I am digging out. finger crossed.

Comment: did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi, yes. We downgrade  python 36 to 35 and solve the issue but it comes with other problems... so we are still considering other possible solutions

Comment: post an issue in github for pythonnet if you find any bug

Comment: Will do, if there is still no proceed this week,

Comment: Hi Alexander Huang ,  can you tell me how you downloaded the pythonnet ? Throught Nuget ? What was the architecture of the pythonnet ? x86 or x64 ? I am trying to get my environment to work to no avail.